# Eliminar elemento de lista pasado un tiempo determinado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una entrada de datos cada cierto tiempo que se va almacenando en una lista sin que se interrumpa , me gustaría que los elementos se eliminaran de la lista pasados 120 segundos.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
import random
import time



almacen=[]
def inicio():
    global almacen
    
    variable=(random.randint(0,10000))
    print (variable)
    
    almacen.append(variable)
    print (almacen)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    
while True:
    inicio()
```

Según el consejo de Candid Moe , he conseguido almacenar la variable junto a una fecha, creo una tupla con dos entradas(entrada,fecha), y las voy almacenado en una lista, asi luego podre buscar las tuplas mas antiguas, no se como puedo comparar dos fechas en un condicional para que pasados dos minutos elimine la tupla,
¿alguien me ayuda a resolverlo?

```
import random
import time
import datetime



tupla_almacen=()
lista_almacen=[]
def inicio():
    global tupla_almacen
    global lista_almacen
    
    variable=(random.randint(0,10000))
    hora=(datetime.datetime.now())

    
    print (variable)
    
    tupla_almacen=(variable,hora.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    
    lista_almacen.append(tupla_almacen)
    print (lista_almacen)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    
while True:
    inicio()
```

Comment: Almacena los objetos como una tupla (objeto, timestamp). Tienes la fecha de creación; puedes hacer un recorrido cada tanto tiempo eliminando las más antiguas.

Comment: Gracias! ya capto la idea, voy a ver si puedo desarrollarlo.

Comment: Si lo resuelves, puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y ganar puntos.

Comment: Me falta solo el condicional para ver cuando han pasado dos minutos entre fechas

Comment: Lo más fácil es usar `int(time.time())`, que te devuelve el número de segundos desde epoch. Usas eso para obtener el timestamp de cuando agregas el objeto a la lista. Luego usa la misma función para obtener el "segundo actual" y le restas el timestamp del objeto. Ahi tienes los segundos transcurridos desde que pusiste el objeto en la lista.

Comment: Lo tengo! gracias Candid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí pongo la solución por si alguien lo necesita:

```
import random
import time
import datetime

lista_almacen=[]

def inicio():
    global lista_almacen
    
    variable=(random.randint(0,10000))
    hora=(int(time.time()))

    
    print (lista_almacen)
    
    tupla_almacen=(str(variable),hora)
    
    lista_almacen.append(tupla_almacen)

    
    for x in lista_almacen:
        if (hora - x[1]) >= int (120):
            print (("Elimino") + str (x))
            lista_almacen.remove(x)
            

        
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    
while True:
    inicio()
```